# Converting padded string to fixed decimal in Alteryx

Tags: string, type-conversion, flat-file, alteryx

I have a large text file with no headers with fields delimited by a fixed width.  All numeric fields are padded with zeros.  I want to import this into Alteryx using field settings from a flat file.

Some of my fields should have the format Fixed Decimal, for example the "Regular Cost" column is a fixed decimal 9.04 - 5 decimal places before the decimal point and four following.  Input example is "000026300".  Desired output is 2.63.

I can't figure out the Length and Scale requirements for this to work.

Length = 9, Scale = 4 gives the error

> Regular Cost: "000023600.0000" was too long to fit in this FixedDecimal.

[Example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nXWAU.png)

Answer (score 1):

Apparently it doesn't like the missing decimal point.  If you read the file as a string, then add the decimal to the correct location in the string, e.g. read it in and force the field length to 10, then use the formula...

```
Left([Field_1],5) + "." + Left(Right([Field_1],4),3)
```

... it will look as expected. Then you can map it to a Double or a FixedDecimal 10.4

Comment: Thanks John!  That is what I ended up doing - I brought the field in as a V_String, then used a similar formula to your above suggestion and then used Select to change the format.